# Qbittorrent docker webui: nothing happen on default password

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker, qbittorrent

When I enter `admin/adminadmin` it just clears up all fields without any error msg, no webui appears just same login screen.
When I deliberately enter wrong password, then error msg appear ("Invalid Username or Password.")

So I assume the login `admin/adminadmin` is correct but something broken with my docker?
I used ghcr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent on my raspberry pi 4.

Comment: maybe its because libseccomp2, as detailed in https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp .

What OS version are you using ?
I'm using raspberryOS, and bumping into the same problem.

Comment: maybe.. but I was hoping docker will save me from having to manage dependencies/look for problems, so I lost my interest after I installed qbittorent-nox via apt install, and everything works. My OS is retropie without X env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed the problem is with libseccomp2, as stated in https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#libseccomp

Had the same issue. Updating libseccomp2 to 2.4.4 (from 2.3.3/the distro version), as stated in https://docs.linuxserver.io/faq#option-3
solved it.

In my case, i had to update docker to version 20 (from 18/distro version) too. Thanks to Roxedus for pointing that out (https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-qbittorrent/issues/112#issuecomment-802689437).